# Velocity JS Lag

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity.js

I have been using parallax for some time and I have been using CSS animations , transforms and etc in order to get the results that I want. But after reading some stuff about Velocity , thought giving it a try.

The problem is the animations are having some kind of delay. Probably because I'm not applying velocity correctly, but I have researched and it seems that I'm doing is correct.

```
$ability.velocity({
  translateX: '-50px',
  opacity: '0'
});

$(document).on('scroll', function(){
 var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
 if(wScroll > $('.ability-self').offset().top - $(window).height()/1.2){
  $ability.velocity({
    translateX: "0",
    opacity: '1'
  });
 } else{
  $ability.velocity({
    translateX: '-70px',
    opacity: 0
  });
}
```

The problem with that is that the animation only happens 1 or 2 seconds after I scroll after the element. I have checked if any CSS attribute might be interfering, but I didn't find a relevant one.

Is my JS bad?

Comment: can you create a jsFiddle or something demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your use of Velocity is correct, your code is causing a lot of stress for the browser.
What you should do is first cache the layout values that don't change:

```
var window_h = $(window).height()/1.2
```

and:

```
var ability_top = $('.ability-self').offset().top
```

And second, debounce the `scroll` event handler, since scroll is triggered *a lot* and you only need to respond once every frame, or possibly even less. For debouncing you could use lodash's or Underscore's `_.debounce()` or just copy paste the implementation, so your code would look like:

```
$(document).on('scroll', _.debounce(function(){
    // code here...
}, 50))
```

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't work. Checked and rechecked. Maybe its the way I'm using velocity.

Comment: It would be a huge help if you could set up a running example on jsFiddle or codepen.io